# The proof that the direct sum of abelian groups is a submodule of the direct product of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, modules

have no idea how to prove(ii), could anyone give me a hint please?

[image]

Comment: The only problems I could imagine here are 1) You don't know what an element of $\sum A_i$ is, or $\prod A_i$, or you don't know either, or 2) You don't know what a submodule is.  Can you clarify where your difficulty lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero is in the direct sum. Now if $\{a_{i}\}$ and $\{b_{i}\}$ are in the direct sum, then $\{i\in I: a_{i}+b_{i}\ne 0\}\subseteq\{i\in I: a_{n}\ne 0\}\cup\{i\in I: b_{n}\ne 0\}$ is finite, so $\{a_{i}+b_{i}\}$ is in the direct sum.

$\{i\in I: ra_{i}\ne 0\}\subseteq\{i\in I: a_{i}\ne 0\}$ is finite, so $\{ra_{i}\}$ is in the direct sum. In particular, $\{-a_{i}\}$ is in the direct sum which serves as the additive inverse to $\{a_{i}\}$.